# Basic probability question: Regarding recurring events with different probability.

Tags: probability

This question stems from me wanting to know what chance I have of getting into a program offered at certain schools based on the percentage chance of me getting into each school.

Suppose I have 9 Die. Each Having a different number of sides. Each die has a different probability of rolling a 1. How would I calculate the chances rolling a 1 at least once if I roll all 9 die exactly once?

The probabilities of rolling a 1 for each die: 9%, 15%, 16%, 20%, 37%, 40%, 51%, 55%, 57%.

I only need to figure out how to do this so there is no need to calculate the probability if you do not want to.

Comment: Subtract the probability of not getting a 1 on each die from $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P(at least 1 one) = 1- P(no ones) = 1- (1-.09)(1-.15)...(1-.57)